# Cannot display title(String) and image from array to CollectionView in swift 4

Tags: arrays, image, swift4, collectionview

I have a collection view and array with URLs of different images. I would like to display titles and images in the collection view. But I can't display and there is no error message found.
How can achieve it? In the console, all results can show. I have no idea how to do it.

```
  import UIKit
  import Foundation
  import SwiftyJSON


class MainPageController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{

 public var foodImage = [UIImageView]()
 public var foodTitle = [String]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    return foodTitle.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainPageCollectionViewCell

    cell.FoodTitle.text = self.foodTitle[indexPath.item]

    //cell.Food.image = foodImage[indexPath.item] as? UIImage
    return cell
}

var fullScreenSize :CGSize!

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var DisplayDateAndTime: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //retrieve screen size
    fullScreenSize =
        UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    // setup backgroud color
    self.view.backgroundColor =
        UIColor.white

    fetchFoodList()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func getCurrentDateTime(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    //formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    let str = formatter.string(from: Date())
    DisplayDateAndTime?.text = str
}
}

  extension MainPageController{
   public func fetchFoodList(){

    let url = URL(string: SomeUrlString)

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let urlContent = data{
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data:data!)
                    let recipes = json["hits"]
                    self.foodTitle =  json["hits"].arrayValue.map {$0["recipe"]["label"].stringValue}
                    print(self.foodTitle)

                    var foodImage =  json["hits"].arrayValue.map {$0["recipe"]["image"].stringValue}

                    print(foodImage)
                    print(self.foodImage)

                }
                catch{
                    print("JSON Processing Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

Here is the result in the console:
["Chicken Vesuvio", "Chicken Paprikash", "Chicken Gravy", "Catalan Chicken", "Persian Chicken", "Kreplach (Chicken Dumplings)", "Dijon Chicken", "Roast Chicken", "Chicken cacciatore", "Tarragon Chicken"]
["https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e42/e42f9119813e890af34c259785ae1cfb.jpg", "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e12/e12b8c5581226d7639168f41d126f2ff.jpg", "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/fd1/fd1afed1849c44f5185720394e363b4e.jpg", "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/4d9/4d9084cbc170789caa9e997108b595de.jpg", "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/8f8/8f810dfe198fa3e520d291f3fcf62bbf.jpg"]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set your collectionView's delegate and datasource in a dataSource function (`collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`) which can not work.

Instead set the delegate and datasource in your viewController's viewDidLoad or since you are using storyboard directly in the interface builder.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    //retrieve screen size
    fullScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    // setup backgroud color
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    fetchFoodList()
}
```

Make also sure to call collectionView.reloadData() in the completion block of fetchFoodList().

```
func fetchFoodList() {

   let url = URL(string: SomeUrlString)

   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in

   if error != nil{
       print(error!)
   } else {
        if let urlContent = data{
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data:data!)
                let recipes = json["hits"]
                self.foodTitle =  json["hits"].arrayValue.map {$0["recipe"]["label"].stringValue}
                print(self.foodTitle)

                var foodImage =  json["hits"].arrayValue.map {$0["recipe"]["image"].stringValue}

                print(foodImage)
                print(self.foodImage)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("JSON Processing Failed")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I have set collectionView.dataSource = self and collectionView.delegate = self in the viewDidLoad but it still can't display.

Comment: I updated my answer, you have to call collectionView.reloadData() after updating its dataSource to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set collectionView's datasource and delegate into your viewController's viewDidLoad not in `(collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:)`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    //retrieve screen size
    fullScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    // setup backgroud color
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    fetchFoodList()
}
```

Comment: I have set collectionView.dataSource = self and collectionView.delegate = self in the viewDidLoad but it still can't display.

Comment: try to reload collection view after getting array list self.collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: It still failed to display array image_url and title.